# Yii - How to display display captcha in CPortlet?

Tags: yii

I'm using portlet to display contact form - the very same as is on static page which comes generated as standard. I'm using the same ContactForm model. The form displays but captcha is not displaying and reports "CCaptchaValidator.action "captcha" is invalid. Unable to find such an action in the current controller."

I'm new to yii so it takes awfully lot of time to figure everything out. Any quick advice what I shell do to make it working?

Best!

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CPortlet');

class ContactFormCard extends CPortlet
{
    public $title='Contact';

protected function renderContent()
{
    $model=new ContactForm;
    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
        if($model->validate())
            $this->controller->refresh();
    }
    $this->render('contactFormCard',array('model'=>$model));
}
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
        ),
    );
}
```

}

and in portlet view:

```
<?php if(CCaptcha::checkRequirements()): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
        <div>
        <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="hint">Please enter the letters as they are shown in the image above.
        <br/>Letters are not case-sensitive.</div>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: please write "view" code, where you are displaying captcha

Comment: it is pretty much copy-paste from contact.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you SiteController.php add:

```
    public function actions() {
        return array(
            'captcha' => array(
                'class' => 'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor' => 0xFFFFFF,
            ),

            // [...]
        );
    }
```

In you ContactForm.php add:

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        // [...]

        array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty' => !CCaptcha::checkRequirements(), 'message' => Yii::t('formsErros', 'Código de verificação incorreto.')),

        // [...]
    );
}
```

In you view.php

```
<!-- [...] -->

<?php if(CCaptcha::checkRequirements()): ?>
    <div class="captcha">
            <?=$form->labelEx($contactFormModel, 'verifyCode')?>
            <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha', array('clickableImage' => true, 'showRefreshButton' => true, 'imageOptions' => array('id' => 'captchaContactForm', 'class' => 'clickableCursor'), 'buttonLabel' => '')); ?>
            <?=$form->textField($contactFormModel, 'verifyCode', array('class' => 'verticalAlignBottom'))?> 
            <?=$form->error($contactFormModel, 'verifyCode')?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- [...] -->
```

Comment: thanks, tried (I actually had it almost the same) and I'm getting exactly same message.

Comment: This message: "CCaptchaValidator.action "captcha" is invalid. Unable to find such an action in the current controller."? You need add the code on Controller, please, post the code of you Controller.

Comment: Yeah it is in the controller exactly as you wrote.

Comment: my bad, now it is working. I was trying to place actions method in protlet.

Comment: Hehe, you had added a "public function actions()" on the form was not it?

Comment: I had it in portlet. easy to mix up for noob.